# About the ergodic theorem of Brikhoff in the context of acompact Riemannian manifold.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ergodic-theory

Let $V$ be a compact Riemannian manifold, $G$ the set of diffeomofphism of $V$, le $\nu$ be a probability measure in $G$. Suppose that $\exp_{x}$ is diffeomorphism in $\mathcal{B}_{2I}(x)\subset V$ ball of radius $2I$ for all $x\in V$, then we define
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\delta_{1}(T) & ={\displaystyle \sup\left\{\left.\frac{d\left(T(x),T(y)\right)}{\left\|\exp_{x}^{-1}y\right\|} \: \right| \: (x,y)\in V^{2}, \:\: 0<d(x,y)\leq I \right\} } \\
\delta_{2}(T) &= {\displaystyle  \sup\left\{ \left. \frac{\left\| \exp_{T(x)}^{-1}T(y)-DT(x)\exp_{x}^{-1}y \right\|}{\left\| \exp_{x}^{-1}y \right\|}    \:\right|\: (x,y)\in V^{2},\: 0<d(x,y)\leq I,\: d(T(x),T(y))\leq I \right\}  }.
\end{array}
$$
Now suppose that:
$$
(H) \qquad \int \log^{+}\left( \delta_{1}(T)+\delta_{2}(T) \right)\nu (dT) <\infty.
$$
Let $\Omega=G^{\mathbb{Z}}$, this is measurable space with product measure $\mathbb{P}=\nu^{\otimes \mathbb{Z}} $, and we consider the proyectión  $T_{i}:\Omega\rightarrow G$, that is, if $\tau$ is the right traslation  then $T_{i}(\tau\omega)=T_{i+1}(\omega)$.

Show that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\log^{+}\left( \delta_{1}(T_{n})+\delta_{2}(T_{n}) \right)=0.  \tag{1}$$

**Remark:** This question arises because I am trying to understand the  article in this [link](http://archive.numdam.org/article/AIHPB_1987__23_1_111_0.pdf) (see pags 6,7), the author says that (1) is a consequence of the hypothesis (H) and the Birkhoff's ergodic theorem. I do not see how (1) you can follow these two facts, I would appreciate someone helping me to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\varphi\circ\tau^k
=\frac n{n+1}\left(\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\varphi\circ\tau^k
+\frac1n\varphi\circ\tau^n\right).
$$
By Birkhoff's ergodic theorem, for an integrable function $\varphi$ the averages
$$
\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\varphi\circ\tau^k\quad\text{and}\quad \frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\varphi\circ\tau^k
$$
converge almost everywhere, of course to the same limit. Hence, $\frac1n\varphi\circ\tau^n$ converges to zero almost everywhere.